# ALSA sound cannot get below 18%

Tags: alsa

My in-ear earphones are very loud, and I want to get them to be quieter. alsamixer works until it gets to 18% or "-45 dB". Then when I want it get even quieter, it jumps all the way to zero. 5 or 6 percent would be nicer for my loud earphones.

Of course I know I can set the volume really low in all my applications, but is there a way to fix this? Also, I notice the sound volume seems to go up in jumps of around 10%...i.e. the volume control seems to have very low resolution.

My sound card is HDA Intel with "chip" SigmaTel STAC 9200. My operating system is Debian 7.0 Wheezy Release Candidate 1, and my desktop system is XFCE. I do not use PulseAudio.

Comment: Post your alsa-info.sh results on alsa-dev mailing list and tell them what you posted here.

Comment: I guess your mainboard (whatever it is) doesn't have a specific headphones output or mixer control?

Comment: No it doesn't; it's a damn ancient laptop (Dell Inspiron 640m) that I'm temporarily using since my main laptop's screen broke and I have no desktop monitor to connect my main laptop to.